# How can I send message to clients every x seconds when running a tornado server?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have Python code like this:

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        print "origin: " + origin
        return True
    # the client connected
    def open(self):
        print "New client connected"
        self.write_message("You are connected")
    # the client sent the message
    def on_message(self, message):
        print "message: " + message
        self.write_message(message)
    # client disconnected
    def on_close(self):
        print "Client disconnected"

socket = tornado.web.Application([(r"/wss", WebSocketHandler),])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socket.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

while True:
    readmydata()
    #send message to all connected clients
    time.sleep(3)
```

How can I start the websocket server, but continue with the python code that sends the message to all connected clients? The script blocks at `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()`, so my `while True` loop never runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout) to call a method every X number of seconds from within the Tornado event loop. To send a message to all conncected clients, you'll need to maintain a global list of each connected client, which you update on each connection/disconnection.

```
clients = []

class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        print "origin: " + origin
        return True
    # the client connected
    def open(self):
        print "New client connected"
        self.write_message("You are connected")
        clients.append(self)

    # the client sent the message
    def on_message(self, message):
        print "message: " + message
        self.write_message(message)

    # client disconnected
    def on_close(self):
        print "Client disconnected"
        clients.remove(self)

def send_message_to_clients():
    try:
        read_my_data()
        for client in clients:
            # Do whatever
    finally:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(timedelta(seconds=3),
                                                     send_message_to_clients)

socket = tornado.web.Application([(r"/wss", WebSocketHandler),])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socket.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(timedelta(seconds=3),
                                                 send_message_to_clients)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: gives me: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "websocketservertest.py", line 41, in <module>
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(timedelta(seconds=3),send_message_to_clients)
NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined

Comment: @Stefan You need to add `from datetime import timedelta`

Comment: thanks. Can you pls update the imports in your answer :) Thank you

Answer (score -1):

A simpler approach:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import socket
import random
import threading
import time

'''
This is a simple Websocket Echo server that uses the Tornado websocket handler.
Please run `pip install tornado` with python of version 2.7.9 or greater to install tornado.
This program will echo back the reverse of whatever it recieves.
Messages are output to the terminal for debuggin purposes. 
''' 

clients = []

def updateClients():

    while True:       

        for c in clients:
            c.write_message('your update data')

        time.sleep(1) #in seconds you can use float point


class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):    

    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        clients.append(self)

    def on_message(self, message):       

        self.write_message('echo ' + message)

    def on_close(self):
        clients.remove(self)

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    t = threading.Thread(target = updateClients)
    t.start()

    #start the thread before tornado

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print '*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```